# FreeRTOS for PIC32MX120F064H using MPLABX IDE

Tags: c, microcontroller, freertos, mplab, pic32

I want to use FreeRTOS for PIC32MX120F064H using MPLABX IDE. I tried a lot but couldn't find any simple LED blinking project for this specific microcontroller that I am using. I even tried demo projects given by FreeRTOS but they are for specific microcontrollers and doesn't work with my microcontroller. I only need the project structure (meaning what/how files to include) and a  simple LED blinking demo. I know from the FreeRTOS site that we have to include task.c, queue.c and list.c as basic files but I tried everything but no luck. Please somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

The FreeRTOS.org site has [a page describing how to convert a demo](https://www.freertos.org/porting-a-freertos-demo-to-different-hardware.html) from one device in an MCU family to another device in the same family.  Alternatively have the MPLAB Harmony tool create a FreeRTOS project for your chip.